# OpenSSL linking: missing extern Symbol BIGNUM_it

Tags: c, linker, openssl

I want to use some features of OpenSSL(1.0.1j) on multiple devices. One requirement is to minimize the size of the code. The OpenSSL code is linked statically to mine. I am only using the RSA_public_decrypt, BIO and PEM->RSA decoding methods. To achieve this, i'm currently compiling OpenSSL not the standard autotools way. I have already stripped out some code that i never use. The only symbol i can not resolve is _BIGNUM_it.

It is declared in `asn1t.h` with:

```
DECLARE_ASN1_ITEM(BIGNUM)
```

and

```
#define DECLARE_ASN1_ITEM(name) \
 extern const ASN1_ITEM name##_it;
```

It is used in `rsa_asn1.c`:

```
ASN1_SIMPLE(RSA, n, BIGNUM),
ASN1_SIMPLE(RSA, e, BIGNUM),
```

which resolves to:

```
#define ASN1_SIMPLE(stname, field, type) ASN1_EX_TYPE(0,0, stname, field, type)
```

and

```
#define ASN1_EX_TYPE(flags, tag, stname, field, type) { \
    (flags), (tag), offsetof(stname, field),\
    #field, ASN1_ITEM_ref(type) }
```

and

```
#define ASN1_ITEM_ref(iptr) (&(iptr##_it))
```

I searched for other symbols used that way. They were implemented using `IMPLEMENT_ASN1_TYPE()`. I searched all OpenSSL Code for something like that using BIGNUM and didn't find anything. Also I tried to use IMPLEMENT_ASN1_TYPE(BIGNUM) in the code, which resulted in thousands of errors.

Is this something provided from the outside? Do i miss a .c file? If yes, which?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the symbol in `asn1/x_bignum.c`.